# Can i call a method and redirect to another page together from p:commandLink

Tags: java, primefaces

Is it possible to call a Java method and redirect to another .xhtml page from one p:commandLink at the same time and how?

My commandLink is:

```
<p:commandLink
                        value="Click Here" action="#{userRequestBean.cancelRequest()}"
                        update = ":dataGrid" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userRequestBean.request}"
                            value="${userActiveRequest}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
```

And i would like when I click the link, also to be redirected to another page (as well as to call a java method)

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Explain in detail.

Comment: Added some more information in the question description.

Comment: You're already doing that. You're calling cancelRequest method as an action. You just return the name of outcome for an another xhtml which you define in faces-config.xml.

Comment: I can't understand you. Can you give me an example? Lets say that the name of the other page is cancelledRequest.xml how should i modify my code to work? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add navigation in your `faces-config.xml`

```
<navigation-rule>           
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>cancelRequest</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/cancelledRequest.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

**Now in your managed bean :**

```
public String cancelRequest(){
//do your logic here

return "cancelRequest";

}
```

Now if you press that commandLink it will redirect to your cancelrequest.xhtml.